# Locomotive CMS Liquid template issue

Tags: locomotivecms

Just upgraded the locomotivecms engine from an older 2.0.x version to 2.1.0

Everything worked great except for tags referencing .css and .js assets

Specifically: {{ 'bootstrap.css' | stylesheet_tag }} results in the following error on screen

Liquid error: bad component(expected relative path component): https://com.citrrus.locomotive.s3.amazonaws.com/sites/51970154b5dd470002000004/theme/stylesheets/bootstrap.css

I've confirmed this is not an issue related to upgrading the engine version by deploying a fresh install of 2.1.0. I created new pages, snippets, and assets from scratch and I still get the above error.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Locomotive 2.1.0.

Didier and the NoCoffee team pushed a fix in version 2.1.1

https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/issues/713